# How to check if a parameter['which can be variable'] is in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm in this freecodecamp problem where I have to add or subtract a global variable. the condition is

1. if the parameter is 2,3,4,5,6 i have to add 1.
2. if the parameter is 7,8,9 don't add/subtract only 0.
3. if the parameter is 10,J,Q,K,A subtract 1(-1).

I have placed the conditions in an array inside the function. I don't know how to check if the parameter/argument is a string.

this is my code. which expects to output '5 bet' but I have an output of '4 bet':

```
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
// Only change code below this line

var plusOne = [2,3,4,5,6]; // <- +1 if the argument is here
var zero = [7,8,9]; // <- 0 if the argument is here
var negative =[10,'J','Q','K','A']; // <- -1 if the argument is here

if(plusOne.indexOf(card)) {
count+=1; 

} else if(zero.indexOf(card)) {
count+=0;

} else if(negative.indexof(card)) {
count+=-1;

}
// return count output
if(count>1) {
output = count + ' Bet'; //<- global
return output.toString();
} else { //<-- if below zero
output = count + ' Hold';
return output.toString();
}


// Only change code above this line
}

// Add/remove calls to test your function.
// Note: Only the last will display
cc(2); cc(3); cc(4); cc(5); cc(6); //<-- call
```

result on [javascript compiler](https://repl.it/CmO6)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: side note: if it doesn't modify `count` you don't need to check for it

Comment: i am resulting to 4 bet instead of 5 bet. i have array 2,3,4,5,6 and on call. the parameters are 2,3,4,5,6 which is in the array so it's +1 for each, but output is only 4. and also, if the parameter is a string, how do I check that if it is on the array? @LittleAlien

Comment: @Polyov i have console.log the output on javascript compiler please check https://repl.it/CmO6

Comment: indexOf(2) is going to equal 0, which is falsy. (Same with 7 and 10).

Comment: *"if the parameter is a string, how do I check that if it is on the array?"* - You use `.indexOf()` regardless of whether it is a string or a number, but you have to check `if (indexOf(val) != -1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What indexOf() does

`indexOf()` returns the position of the item in an array as an integer if it's there and -1 if it's not. [Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

### Your Error

When you try to find card 2, `indexOf()` will return it's position as index 0 as it is the first element in the array.

Index 0 is then casted to boolean by your if statement which is false. Therefore one addition is missing and you have a result of `4 Bet` instead of `5 Bet`

### What you should do instead

Check against the element not found condition of `indexOf()` which returns -1.